# How do I add hyperlinks to my Sharepoint survey questions?

Tags: survey-list

I have this Sharepoint survey question that I want to put a hyperlink into.  When I just paste an URL in, it doesn't hyperlink it.  Can I put HTML into column names (survey questions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't (tested on Sharepoint Foundation 2010). It doesn't look like there's a facility for putting links into the questions either.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible, please follow these links:

[Using simple JS and content web part](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/sharepoint-add-instructions-and-color.html)

OR

[Using JQuery and changing site Master page - more dangerous than 1-st method!!!](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/09/29/adding-images-links-to-a-sharepoint-2010-survey/)